# Any way to show a selected number of list items without having to add a conditional to each?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So let's say I have a list.

```
<div>
   <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I only want every item after Item1 to be visible once a user clicks a button.
I could do this easily by creating a boolean called showItem, set it to false and then create a click event that sets it to true in a method.

```
<div @click="showItemBtn">
   <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li v-if="showItem">Item2</li>
      <li v-if="showItem">Item3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

method: {
   showItemBtn() {
      this.showItem = true
     }
   }
```

But is there a more clean way of doing this, so I don't have to add a v-if statement to every single item that comes after Item1?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a `v-for` logic to the `items` with a reactive bool value with adding the click logic in the template. Here You don't need to have the click methoh in the Vue logic.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    showItem: false,
    // You can add your list items here
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div @click="showItem = true">
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li v-for="index in 3" v-if="showItem">Item{{ index + 1 }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the elements into the `<template>` element and use the `v-if` directive to the `<template>` only once.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      showItem: false,
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div @click="showItem = !showItem">
      <ul>
        <li>Item1</li>
        <template v-if="showItem">
          <li>Item2</li>
          <li>Item3</li>
        </template>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If looping is possible you can try the below way as well. I used the key as a unique id for demonstration, you can use anything which is unique.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      items: ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'],
      showItem: false
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div @click="showItem = !showItem">
    <ul>
      <template v-for="(item,index) in items">
        <!-- If first item show direct otherwise check condition -->
        <li :key="index" v-if="index == 0 || showItem">
          {{ item }}
        </li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```